# Generating Google Calendar Share URL

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar, android-calendar

Do someone have any idea about how to generate 'Google calendar share url for event'? I tried many methods; but couldn't find how can i do.

I want to make a 'add to calendar' button for my event, which will redirect users to the page at below:

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/share?slt=1AaoAQDb2PYlse_1Lz_ciozRLzNJ-VgAnhYftB1xTv3DRl_oFiuhaZk9NLMryIyn3qB5FnHs36Fe7kgzEZc1p2X6tTV6sDocFOFLW

As you can see with the link above, there is an special Google Calendar landing page with this URL; but i couldn't understand where it takes **slt** variable. (if i can find **slt** variable, it can be enough for me)

ps: i am not asking as the url: https://calendar.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&tmeid=MnBhcmg1dnRnamUydW85ZjEzM3JmMDAyM3QgZXJzYW5AZXJzYW5lcnR1cmsuY29t&tmsrc=whocarez%40gmail.com